# In heat map chart value of x-axis are not displaying in fusion charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm using angular-fusion charts directive in my application. I've created heat map chart from one of the examples. I'm stuck as in my application values of x-axis are not displaying. I'm unable to find what's wrong with this.

```
var salesHMChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'heatmap',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '470',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource:  {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Downtime Reasons",
                "bgColor": "ffffff",
                "outCnvBaseFontSize": "10",
                "outCnvBaseFontColor": "000000",
                "canvasBgColor": "ffffff",
                "toolTipColor": "ffffff",
                "showXaxisLabels": "1",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5",
                "hdivLineColor": "e8700e",
                "vdivLineColor": "e8700e",
                "showborder": "0",
                "showPlotBorder": "1",
                "plotBorderColor": "e8700e",
                "canvasBorderColor": "e8700e"
            },
            "columns": {
                "column": [
                    {
                        "id": "1123741",
                        "label": "order 1123741"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "858546",
                        "label": "order 858546"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "rowid": "Limpieza Input",
                            "columnid": "1123741",
                            "value": "1",
                            "tllabel": "Limpieza Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #1123741"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Marcha Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "27",
                            "tllabel": "Marcha Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Averia KKE Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "2",
                            "tllabel": "Averia KKE Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Documentacion Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "1",
                            "tllabel": "Documentacion Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "7",
                            "tllabel": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Limpieza Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "5",
                            "tllabel": "Limpieza Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "1",
                            "tllabel": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "No laborable Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "5",
                            "tllabel": "No laborable Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "Sin trabajo Input",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "14",
                            "tllabel": "Sin trabajo Input",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        },
                        {
                            "rowid": "ST Maq. parada",
                            "columnid": "858546",
                            "value": "1",
                            "tllabel": "ST Maq. parada",
                            "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "colorrange": {
                "gradient": "1",
                "minvalue": "1",
                "code": "fce797",
                "startlabel": "Low",
                "endlabel": "High",
                "color": [
                    {
                        "maxvalue": "4",
                        "code": "f74c25",
                        "label": "Medium"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "c71610",
                        "maxvalue": "7"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    })
    .render();
});
```

Here is the Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4foh868/4/)

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm surprised after changing column id `1123741` to `112741` and remove whole columns object. It's working. As I can't change data obviously, I want to find why it's not working!! :(

Comment: Very interesting problem. Well when you do not explicitly define the rows and column object, Heatmap tries to get it from the data (automatically). Here as you have defined the rows section and not the columns it probably gets confused. But removing the columns section altogether should have made it functional. Surprisingly, I am yet to find out why the problem relates to that particular no. The problem also disappear if you place the first object after another. Seems like an issue.

Comment: @pallabB Yes, it seems like an issue. I posted in fusion charts forums too. They said number of digit in columnid should be same but it should not as expected so they passed this issue to the development team. Let's see what they said now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var salesHMChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'heatmap',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '470',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource:  {
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Downtime Reasons",
        "bgColor": "ffffff",
        "outCnvBaseFontSize": "10",
        "outCnvBaseFontColor": "000000",
        "canvasBgColor": "ffffff",
        "toolTipColor": "ffffff",
        "showValues": "1",
         "xAxisLabelsOnTop": "1",
        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
        "toolTipPadding": "5",
        "hdivLineColor": "e8700e",
        "vdivLineColor": "e8700e",
        "showborder": "0",
        "showPlotBorder": "1",
        "plotBorderColor": "e8700e",
        "canvasBorderColor": "e8700e"
    },
            "rows": {
        "row": [
            {
                "id": "r1",
                "label": "Limpieza Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "r2",
                "label": "Marcha Input"
            }
            ]
            },      

    "columns": {
        "column": [
            {
                "id": "c1",
                "label": "order 1123741"
            },
            {
                "id": "c2",
                "label": "order 858546"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dataset": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "rowid": "r1",
                    "columnid": "c1",
                    "value": "1"

                },
                {
                    "rowid": "r1",
                    "columnid": "c2",
                    "value": "27"

                }

            ]
        }
    ],
    "colorrange": {
        "gradient": "1",
        "minvalue": "1",
        "code": "fce797",
        "startlabel": "Low",
        "endlabel": "High",
        "color": [
            {
                "maxvalue": "4",
                "code": "f74c25",
                "label": "Medium"
            },
            {
                "code": "c71610",
                "maxvalue": "7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
    })
    .render();
});
```

Comment: It's look like you've changed my almost data and implement different way. Can you please let me know what's wrong in my code? And to get that work what should I do?

Comment: you have to add "rows" property in our product.
Because fusioncharts had some property which allow you to render your charts with different style. . 
Here "rows" property take as yaxis label and "columns" as xaxis label ..

Answer (score 0):

I Hope This Will Help You

```
var salesHMChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'heatmap',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '550',
                height: '470',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "Downtime Reasons",
                        "bgColor": "ffffff",
                        "outCnvBaseFontSize": "10",
                        "outCnvBaseFontColor": "000000",
                        "canvasBgColor": "ffffff",
                        "toolTipColor": "ffffff",
                        "showXaxisLabels": "1",
                        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                        "toolTipPadding": "5",
                        "hdivLineColor": "e8700e",
                        "vdivLineColor": "e8700e",
                        "showborder": "0",
                        "showPlotBorder": "1",
                        "plotBorderColor": "e8700e",
                        "canvasBorderColor": "e8700e"
                },
                    "columns": {
                        "column": [
                            {
                                "id": "a",
                                "label": "order 1123741"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b",
                                "label": "order 858546"
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    "dataset": [
                        {
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Limpieza Input",
                                    "columnid": "a",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "tllabel": "Limpieza Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #1123741"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Marcha Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "27",
                                    "tllabel": "Marcha Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Averia KKE Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "2",
                                    "tllabel": "Averia KKE Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Documentacion Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "tllabel": "Documentacion Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "7",
                                    "tllabel": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Limpieza Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "5",
                                    "tllabel": "Limpieza Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "tllabel": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "No laborable Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "5",
                                    "tllabel": "No laborable Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "Sin trabajo Input",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "14",
                                    "tllabel": "Sin trabajo Input",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                },
                                {
                                    "rowid": "ST Maq. parada",
                                    "columnid": "b",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "tllabel": "ST Maq. parada",
                                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "colorrange": {
                        "gradient": "1",
                        "minvalue": "1",
                        "code": "fce797",
                        "startlabel": "Low",
                        "endlabel": "High",
                        "color": [
                            {
                                "maxvalue": "4",
                                "code": "f74c25",
                                "label": "Medium"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "c71610",
                                "maxvalue": "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            })
            salesHMChart.render();
        });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -1):

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var salesHMChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'heatmap',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '470',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource:  {
    "chart": {
        "caption": "Downtime Reasons",
        "bgColor": "ffffff",
        "outCnvBaseFontSize": "10",
        "outCnvBaseFontColor": "000000",
        "canvasBgColor": "ffffff",
        "toolTipColor": "ffffff",
        "showXaxisLabels": "1",
        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
        "toolTipPadding": "5",
        "hdivLineColor": "e8700e",
        "vdivLineColor": "e8700e",
        "showborder": "0",
        "showPlotBorder": "1",
        "plotBorderColor": "e8700e",
        "canvasBorderColor": "e8700e"
    },

      "rows": {
        "row": [
            {
                "id": "Limpieza Input",
                "label": "Limpieza Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Marcha Input",
                "label": "Marcha Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Averia KKE Input",
                "label": "Averia KKE Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Documentacion Input",
                "label": "Documentacion Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                "label": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                "label": "Mantenimiento planificado Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "No laborable Input",
                "label": "No laborable Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "Sin trabajo Input",
                "label": "Sin trabajo Input"
            },
            {
                "id": "ST Maq. parada",
                "label": "ST Maq. parada"
            }
            ]
            },            


    "columns": {
        "column": [
            {
                "id": "1123741",
                "label": "order 1123741"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_0",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_1",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_2",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_3",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_4",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_5",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_6",
                "label": "order 858546"
            },
            {
                "id": "858546_7",
                "label": "order 858546"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dataset": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "rowid": "Limpieza Input",
                    "columnid": "1123741",
                    "value": "1",
                    "tllabel": "Limpieza Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #1123741"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "Marcha Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_0",
                    "value": "27",
                    "tllabel": "Marcha Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "Averia KKE Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_1",
                    "value": "2",
                    "tllabel": "Averia KKE Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "Documentacion Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_2",
                    "value": "1",
                    "tllabel": "Documentacion Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_3",
                    "value": "7",
                    "tllabel": "Cambio (Set-Up) Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },

                {
                    "rowid": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_4",
                    "value": "1",
                    "tllabel": "Mantenimiento planificado Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "No laborable Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_5",
                    "value": "5",
                    "tllabel": "No laborable Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "Sin trabajo Input",
                    "columnid": "858546_6",
                    "value": "14",
                    "tllabel": "Sin trabajo Input",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                },
                {
                    "rowid": "ST Maq. parada",
                    "columnid": "858546_7",
                    "value": "1",
                    "tllabel": "ST Maq. parada",
                    "trlabel": "Order #858546"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "colorrange": {
        "gradient": "1",
        "minvalue": "1",
        "code": "fce797",
        "startlabel": "Low",
        "endlabel": "High",
        "color": [
            {
                "maxvalue": "4",
                "code": "f74c25",
                "label": "Medium"
            },
            {
                "code": "c71610",
                "maxvalue": "7"
            }
        ]
    }
}
    })
    .render();
});
```

Comment: why are you changing the data? If it needs to be changed then explain what's wrong with it.